# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit) : variable lengths differ (found for 'train$ID')

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

I'm not very experienced using R but I've been trying to run a random forest in R on a training dataset that seems to work and then getting an error when I use that model to try and predict results for the test data.

I can't show the data but essentially I have test results (from about 70 tests) for about 30000 parts so my columns are each test and the rows are each part. I have a column called fail that indicates with either a 1 or a 0 whether these parts failed in the field or not. I want to train a random forest to try predict passes and fails using a combination of test results.

None of these parts failed an individual test but I'd like to see if maybe high results across a combination of tests could indicate that this part would fail in the field or something of the sort. All the tests in the model are continuous.

The model runs and then I try to predict fails and passes in my test data but I get the following error

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'train$ID')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 7855 rows but variables found have 23560 rows
```

This is my code.

```
### Changing my response variable to a factor 
data$fail <- as.factor(data$fail)

### Divide the passes and fails
passes<-data[grepl(0, data$fail),]
fails<-data[!grepl(0, data$fail),]

### Split the passes and the fails into training and test
splitp <- sample.split(passes$fail, SplitRatio = 0.75)
splitf<- sample.split(fails$fail, SplitRatio = 0.75)
trainp <- subset(passes, splitp == TRUE)
testp <- subset(passes, splitp == FALSE)
trainf <- subset(fails, splitf == TRUE)
testf <- subset(fails, splitf == FALSE)
### Combine training and test passes and fails
train <- rbind(trainp,trainf)
test<- rbind(testp,testf)

library(randomForest)
set.seed(1)
rand.fit<-randomForest(train$fail~.-train$ID - train$t6 - train$t5- train$t4 - train$t3
           - train$t2 - train$t1,data =train, importance=TRUE,ntree=500)

rand.pred<-predict(rand.fit,test)
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could advise me on what I'm doing wrong. I'm sorry if this isn't enough information but I can't share any data.

The variables t1-t6 weren't continuous, they were essentially pass/fail and in this data all parts passed all tests so I haven't included them in the model.

Comment: Remove all instances of `train$` from the model formula. The data.frame is specified with `data = train`. To be able to pass new data to `predict` the model has to be fit from the data.frame passed to the `data` parameter. That's not the case in your code because of your use of `train$` in the model formula.

Comment: Try adding your data using the `dput()` function, maybe only the first rows of your dataset, no need for the entire thing.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's working now!